# Filtering and Sorting a Table that has multiple rows per User row

Tags: tables, filter, data-tables, sort

Here's a good challenge for you all.

**Challenge: Filter by 2 colors, then Sort by 'Amount' and not replicate the user's name throughout the Name column?**

**User Goal: To be able to see which is the lowest amount a user has with a color (or 2 colors).**

*Imagine you have a table that has 5 User Rows.*

The headings for the table are Name - Color - Amount - Cats - Dogs
[image]

User1, User4 and User5 all have more than one color associated to their row group. So they get a totals row. The others only have 1 color so they don't need a totals row.

Each user has a number of cats or dogs.

You could filter easily on color 'red'.
[image]

And you can also filter on 2 colors (red and blue):
[image]

BUT what if.. you wanted to then **SORT** the Red & Blue filtered results by **Amount**?:
[image]

How do you take that Blue 47 out of User 1's group and put it below User4 Red 32 ?? So that it is in Sorted order?

Any suggestions how to make this table better so that it is possible to SORT after Filtering 2 colors and **not replicate the user's name** throughout the Name column? Maybe there is a better way to lay out this table.

Thank you

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand the question. I mean: why anyone would do that? All variables belong to **user 1**, therefore it makes no sense to take the variable outside **user 1** domain. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No worries. I guess if you are sorting on the Amount column, Blue47 for User1 will have to come out and go below User4 Red 32. So that the numbers being sorted are going from low to high (top to bottom).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would change the colours column to fit colors vertical not horizontally.[image]

This would allow , for your example : "BUT what if.. you wanted to then SORT the Red & Blue filtered results by Amount?:" to also change the order in table and the order in the colours column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris. The solution is good. I implemented the solution but other, more complex, problems in the table have now become apparent which I need to solve. I might create another challenge and see what you think. Thank you very much for your time and great solution. I wanted to upvote you but the system says I don't have enough power to do that sorry.

Comment: Also Chris - I added the Part 2 here - https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/143462/filtering-and-sorting-a-table-that-has-multiple-rows-per-user-row-part-2-more